# How to get files from bitbucket with composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

I create private repository on bitbucket with composer.json and vendor directory in it (vendor directory contain php file). There is only master branch
look something like this: https://bitbucket.org/example/composer
and this is composer file:

```
{
  "name": "example/composer",
  "description": "composer repository",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "example\\composer\\": "vendor/"
    }
  }
}
```

and i have composer file on my server:

```
{
  "name" : "example/composer",
  "description" : "composer repository",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:example/composer.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4"
  }
}
```

i just want to download my vendor directory from repository to server when i do composer install
i got connected to bitbucket with ssh correctly
but when i do composer install, i just generate a bunch of autoload files, but my files stay on bitbucket :с
Help pls

Comment: Maybe in your derectory you have .gitignor and into .gitignor maybe you have your vendor?

Comment: @AramMnatsakanyan nope, directory only contains a composer file, and my repository dont have .gitignore at all

Comment: You don't have any dependencies specified in `require` section of `composer.json`. Why do you expect that Composer will install anything?

Comment: @rob006 i dont familiar with composer enought, i tought that autoload psr with path would be enought

Answer (score 0):

The main repository type is the composer repository. It uses a single packages.json file that contains all of the package metadata.

The repository type that packagist uses. To reference a composer repository, supply the path before the packages.json file.

```
{
    "packages": {
        "vendor/package-name": {
            "dev-master": { @composer.json },
            "1.0.x-dev": { @composer.json },
            "0.0.1": { @composer.json },
            "1.0.0": { @composer.json }
        }
    }
}
```

The composer.json marker would be the contents of the composer.json from that package version including as a minimum:

```
//name
//version
//dist or source
//Here is a minimal package definition:
{
  "name": "name/name",
    "version": "verison",
    "dist": 
{
        "url": "**URL**",
        "type": "zip,
    }
}
```